# Can someone point me to more information on this differential equation: $\frac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dt}=Ct$ has the solution $x(t)=Ce^{Ct)}x(0)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the differential equation where the solution to

$$\frac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dt}=Ct$$

is

$$x(t)=Ce^{Ct}x(0) \quad \text{where $C$ is a constant.} $$

Can anyone tell me what type of differential equation this is and/or point me to more resources so I can understand how this solution was derived?

Comment: No,  this is wrong.  The "solution" doesn't satisfy the differential equation, and for $t=0$ the two sides are not the same unless $x(0)=0$ or $C=1$.  I think you mean $\dfrac{dx}{dt} = Cx$ and $x(t) = e^{Ct} x(0)$.

Answer (score 1):

This is a separable equation. One way to see the solution is to rearrange and integrate:
$$
\frac{dx}{dt} = Ct\\
dx = Ctdt
x = \int dx = \int Ctdt = c\frac{t^2}{2}
$$

---

You likely mean the ODE
$$
\frac{dt}{dx} = Ct \iff \frac{dt}{t} = cdx \iff \ln t = cx + K \iff t = x_0e^{cx}
$$

Comment: Thanks got it now! yes I copied someone who copied the equation incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

The differential equation

$$ \frac{dx}{dt} = Cx,$$ with initial condition $x(0)=x_0$ has solution

$$x(t) = x_0 e^{Ct}.$$

The differential equation

$$ \frac{dx}{dt} = Ct,$$ with initial condition $x(0)=x_0$ has solution

$$x(t) = \frac{C}{2} t^2 + x_0.$$

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that that's the correct solution. When you have an OED like that, you will want to integrate both sides with respect to $t$. The left side gives you $x$ by the fundamental theorem of calculus. The right side gives you $C\frac{t^2}{2} + x(0)$. I think any website or text covering basic OED will have this.